# How to fix "Value moved here, in previous iteration of loop"?

Tags: rust, websocket, tauri

I want to write a program that passes messages from a local websocket to an remote and vice versa, but when I add a `while` to spawn threads I get an error. How can I fix this?

The exact same error also shows up with `ws_local`.

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `write_remote`
   |
42 |     let (mut write_remote, mut read_remote) = ws_remote.split();
   |          ---------------- move occurs because `write_remote` has type `SplitSink<WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::MaybeTlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>>, Message>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
70 |         let _handle_two = task::spawn(async move {
   |  ________________________________________________^
71 | |         while let Some(msg) = read_local.next().await {
72 | |           let msg = msg?;
73 | |           if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
74 | |             write_remote.send(msg).await;
   | |             ------------ use occurs due to use in generator
...  |
78 | |         Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
79 | |       });
   | |_______^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

Here is my code:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(
  all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use futures_util::{future, SinkExt, StreamExt, TryStreamExt};
use tokio_tungstenite::{
    connect_async,
    accept_async,
    tungstenite::{Result},
};
use http::Request;
use tokio::sync::oneshot;
use futures::{
  future::FutureExt, // for `.fuse()`
  pin_mut,
  select,
};
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
use std::io;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::thread;
use tokio::spawn;
use tokio::task;

async fn client() -> Result<()> {
  
  // Client
  let request = Request::builder()
    .method("GET")
    .header("Host", "demo.piesocket.com")
    // .header("Origin", "https://example.com/")
    .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
    .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key())
    .uri("wss://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1?api_key=VCXCEuvhGcBDP7XhiJJUDvR1e1D3eiVjgZ9VRiaV&notify_self")
    .body(())?;

  let (mut ws_remote, _) = connect_async(request).await?;
  let (mut write_remote, mut read_remote) = ws_remote.split();
  let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4444").await.expect("Can't listen");
  
  while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
    let mut ws_local = accept_async(stream).await.expect("Failed to accept");
    let (mut write_local, mut read_local) = ws_local.split();

        // read_remote.try_filter(|msg| future::ready(msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary()))
        //   .forward(write_local)
        //   .await
        //   .expect("Failed to forward messages");

        // read_local.try_filter(|msg| future::ready(msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary()))
        //   .forward(write_remote)
        //   .await
        //   .expect("Failed to forward messages");

      let _handle_one = task::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = read_remote.next().await {
          let msg = msg?;
          if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
            write_local.send(msg).await;
          }
        };

        Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
      });
      
      let _handle_two = task::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = read_local.next().await {
          let msg = msg?;
          if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
            write_remote.send(msg).await;
          }
        };

        Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
      });

      // handle_one.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
      // handle_two.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
    }

  Ok(())
}

fn main() {
  tauri::async_runtime::spawn(client());
  tauri::Builder::default()
    // .plugin(PluginBuilder::default().build())
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("failed to run app");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need to make the split streams able to cross threads. The context within the while loop can't access the write_local and write_remote values again and again without a super-context that can hold them.

Here is a working example:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

use futures_util::{SinkExt, StreamExt};
use http::Request;
use tokio::task;
use tokio::{net::TcpListener, sync::Mutex};
use tokio_tungstenite::{accept_async, connect_async, tungstenite::Result};

async fn client() -> Result<()> {
    // Client
    let request = Request::builder()
      .method("GET")
      .header("Host", "demo.piesocket.com")
      // .header("Origin", "https://example.com/")
      .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
      .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
      .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
      .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key())
      .uri("wss://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1?api_key=VCXCEuvhGcBDP7XhiJJUDvR1e1D3eiVjgZ9VRiaV&notify_self")
      .body(())?;

    let (ws_remote, _) = connect_async(request).await?;
    let (write_remote, read_remote) = ws_remote.split();
    let read_remote = Arc::new(Mutex::new(read_remote));
    let write_remote = Arc::new(Mutex::new(write_remote));
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4444")
        .await
        .expect("Can't listen");
    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        let ws_local = accept_async(stream).await.expect("Failed to accept");
        let (mut write_local, mut read_local) = ws_local.split();

        // read_remote.try_filter(|msg| future::ready(msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary()))
        //   .forward(write_local)
        //   .await
        //   .expect("Failed to forward messages");

        // read_local.try_filter(|msg| future::ready(msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary()))
        //   .forward(write_remote)
        //   .await
        //   .expect("Failed to forward messages");
        let read_remote = read_remote.clone();
        let _handle_one = task::spawn(async move {
            let mut read_remote = read_remote.lock_owned().await;
            while let Some(msg) = read_remote.next().await {
                let msg = msg?;
                if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
                    write_local.send(msg).await;
                }
            }

            Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
        });

        let write_remote = write_remote.clone();
        let _handle_two = task::spawn(async move {
            let mut write_remote = write_remote.lock_owned().await;
            while let Some(msg) = read_local.next().await {
                let msg = msg?;
                if msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary() {
                    write_remote.send(msg).await;
                }
            }

            Result::<(), tungstenite::Error>::Ok(())
        });

        // handle_one.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
        // handle_two.await.expect("The task being joined has panicked");
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: Huh, and how can I do that?

Comment: @Grizzly Re-borrow the stream components within the thread context, and then you can use it in the while loop.

Comment: Can you show me a example how do this?

Comment: @Grizzly I tried to fix it using Arc<Mutex<()>>. It is not very performant and you might want to look into channels in the future.
[Code](https://paste.ee/p/yJewc)

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on it for 3 days. Now thanks to you it is working! Really thank you!

Comment: PS. Don't post the code on pastebin only in the answer so everyone can see the solution.

Comment: I still have to figure out how to properly format code on stackoverflow D:

Comment: Like so: [tutorial](https://pastebin.com/rYV6zQLt)

Comment: ```rust
fn main() {
println!("Neat!");
}
```